# How to make Label text expand to the right

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFx and the content of the label will be updated dynamically.
It is currently expanding from the center. I want it to expand to the right.

For example, 'labeltext' is the content of the label initially as follows (with 2 buttons to the label's left):

Initial:

```
Button1 Button2 labeltext
```

I am looking to achieve the following when the label content is updated with a longer String:

```
Button1 Button2 labeltextlabeltextlabeltextlabeltext
```

Current Issue where it expands from the center and covers my button2 as follows. A longer string will end up covering button1 too.

```
Button1 labeltextlabeltextlabeltextlabeltext
```

The buttons and label are inside a StackPane. Portion of code handling the label as follows. Tried the commented out sections which doesn't make a difference:

```
Label pathLabel = new Label("labeltext");
//pathLabel.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
//pathLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
Button btn1 = new Button("Button1");
Button btn2 = new Button("Button2");
StackPane layout = new StackPane();
layout.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2, pathLabel);
```

Comment: Use `HBox` instead of `StackPane`. then you can use this: `HBox.setHgrow(pathLabel, Priority.ALWAYS);`

Comment: @Kachna Will try it out. But is it possible with StackPane?